# aws ssm register-task-with-maintenance-window reports error as Invalid JSON?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssm

I am running the below command and it is reporting an error like Invalid JSON:

**AWS SSM Command:**

```
 aws ssm register-task-with-maintenance-window --window-id mw-06344a0189162e0b3 --targets Key=WindowTargetIds,Values=ae5c621a-17d8-454f-977f-46298f1e6eb8 --task-arn AWS-RunPatchBaseline --service-role-arn arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/AmazonSSMRoleForInstancesQuickSetup --task-type RUN_COMMAND --max-concurrency 2 --max-errors 1 --priority 1 --task-invocation-parameters '{\"Operation\":{\"Values\":[\"Install\"]}}'
```

**Error:**

```
Error parsing parameter '--task-invocation-parameters': Invalid JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
JSON received: {\"Operation\":{\"Values\":[\"Install\"]}}
```

I'm using [the AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-patch-cliwalk.html).

I used double quotes instead of the single quote but still no charm.

Finally, created an [issue](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-systems-manager-user-guide/issues/111) on GitHub for AWS Docs.

Kindly assist if you have come across an issue like this before.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying it wants "double quotes" but your example has single quotes. Maybe [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-patch-cliwalk.html) have been updated since your posting, but it currently recommends the following format.

Linux/Windows:

```
--task-invocation-parameters "RunCommand={Parameters={Operation=Install}}"
```